# How can I add Custom Field settings to all OOB Field types?

Tags: custom-field-types, spfield, custom-control, field-type

I need to add a custom "Check Box" property to all existing OOB SharePoint column types. This should appear in the Additional Column Settings section for any column type created; this property will be used in code by many applications.
Note-I dont want custom field type. I want the "property" for all native field types.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you're attempting to do is possible with the native SharePoint field types.

Normally Custom Field Types define a FieldEditorUserControl that lives in `%SharePoint folder%/TEMPLATE/CONTROLTEMPLATES`. This defines what to show to the users when adding/editing a field type.

**Some** of the native field types have controls in there (`LookupFieldEditor.ascx` for example), but most rely on code built-in to the add/edit page itself (I believe). Editing the controls would be pointless anyway, as you've got no way of adding code-behind, and hence can't actually store the values.

So what you want to achieve can most likely only be done by producing a range of Custom Field Types that inherit from all the native field types and define their own field editor user controls: This would be an extraordinarily large and thankless task.

Comment: A task that if accomplished should be open sourced somewhere for others to reuse. :)

Comment: Or burned as heresy. One of two.

Answer (score 0):

With the OOTB types it is not possible. You would have to build a custom field type in order to do this. See: [Building Custom Field Types in Windows SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684919%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score -4):

You can add your custom field to the native item content type 0x01. Because all content types inherit from it you should find your added custom field on each item into the site collection

Comment: Please improve this answer!

Comment: @pumpax  : Rolled back your edit so that your answer makes sense again. Please flag for deletion if you want to remove it.